# How to search value by specific keyword in array of objects and get it in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How to search an array of objects by keyword and get that object set if exists. 
For example --

```
array(
[0] => Object
    (
        [id] => 123
        [label] => 'Jone Due'
        [title] => 'Bangladeshi Laravel Expert'
    )

[1] => Object
    (
        [id] => 234
        [label] => 'Jone Due'
        [title] => 'Bangladeshi Singer'
    )
[2] => Object
    (
        [id] => 345
        [label] => 'Jone Due'
        [title] => 'Bangladeshi Actor'
    )
    ....

);
```

I want to search `title` with keyword `Laravel`, and result i want to get --

```
array(
[0] => Object
    (
        [id] => 123
        [label] => Jone Due
        [title] => Bangladeshi Laravel Expert
    )
);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: *Is it possible* yes, have you tried anything to solve it yourself so far?

Comment: @NigelRen I am new at laravel. i tried by laravel collection method. like this 
$results->where('title', 'LIKE', "%% Laravel%%"); //Its not working. 
But if try with full title its showing result. 
$results->where('title', 'LIKE', "Bangladeshi Laravel Expert");

Comment: Usually you only have 1 %age sign - so may be `$results->where('title', 'LIKE', "%Laravel%");`

Comment: Yes, I tried 1 %age sign also. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next. It works for me:

```
 $i = 0;      // counter
 $ar = [];    // array of indexes of success objects
 $ar2 = [];   // result array of objects which title has 'Laravel' inside

// $obj_ar must be consists of  objects (it should has some checking code for that requirement)

// filling an array of indexes $ar
 foreach ($obj_ar as $obj_1){
     if (strstr($obj_1->title,'Laravel')) array_push ($ar, $i);
     $i++; 
 }

// building a result array of objects  
 $count_ar = count($ar);

 if ($count_ar>0) {
     for($o = 0; $o < $count_ar; $o++){
        array_push ($ar2, $obj_ar[$o]);
     }
 }

// result array of objects
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ar2);
echo '</pre>';
```

or a bit faster way:

```
 $i = 0;      // counter 
 $ar2 = [];   // result array of objects which title has 'Laravel' inside

// $obj_ar must be consists of  objects (it should has some checking code for that requirement)

// filling an array of indexes $ar
 foreach ($obj_ar as $obj_1){
     if (strstr($obj_1->title,'Laravel')) array_push ($ar2, $obj_ar[$i]);
     $i++; 
 }

// result array of objects
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ar2);
echo '</pre>';
```